# Unable to Call a Method/Function from one class to Another Class in Selenium Using Java

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am new to Selenium & Java so please correct me If I am wrong.
I am trying to call a function from the login class to Another Class but on calling the function, the exception error is displaying on the line of code (Unhandled exception type InterruptedException)
Where, when I create a new function and call it, does not throw any error and works perfectly.
Here is the snippet of code:

```
//This is the Login Class
package GtfDemoPackage;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
public class DemoGtfLogin extends GtfDemoLaunchClass{
@Test
public void loginClass() throws InterruptedException{
driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/header/div/div/div\[2\]/div/ul/li\[8\]/a")).click();
Thread.sleep(2000);
driver.findElement(By.id("email")).sendKeys("demouser10@mailinator.com");
driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("123456");
driver.findElement(By.id("loginBtn")).click();
Thread.sleep(2000);}
@Test
public void loginMessage(){
System.out.println("Login Successfull");}
}

**//This is the class where I am calling the function "loginClass"**

package GtfDemoPackage;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
public class DemoTIZElementaryCertificateDownload extends GtfDemoLaunchClass{
public static void main(String\[\] args){
DemoGtfLogin classObj = new DemoGtfLogin();
classObj.loginClass();} 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String\[\] args){
DemoGtfLogin classObj = new DemoGtfLogin();
classObj.loginClass();} 
}
```

If you are not handling an exception through catch block, it should be declared using throws statement as you have done for loginClass() method.

From main method you are calling the method loginClass() which throws interruptedexception, so declare this exception again using
throws statement for main() method. change main method declaration as follows

```
public static void main(String\[\] args) throws 
InterruptedException{
DemoGtfLogin classObj = new DemoGtfLogin();
classObj.loginClass();} 
}
```

calling method should declare or handle the exception declared by called method. Here interrupedexception is declared in loginClass() method which should be handled or declared by main() method